# How do you disable frame skips in a game, in SFML preferably

Tags: algorithm, sfml, timestep

by frame skip off i mean that the game should just slow down if the fps drops, just like in terraria, i got this code currently and want to implement it to it:

```
static class Globals
{
    static public Time dt = new Time();
    static public Vector2f Friction
    {
        get
        {
            return new Vector2f(2 * dt.AsSeconds(), 0);
        }
    }
}

class Player
{
        private void StartMoving(int _direction)
    {
        moving = true;
        direction = _direction;
        heldfor =  1;
        Move(direction);
    }
    public void Move(int _direction)
    {
        if(!moving)
        {
            StartMoving(_direction);
            return;
        }
        if(direction == _direction)
        {
            if(heldfor < heldforlimit) heldfor++; 
            Velocity += new Vector2f(((speed * (heldfor / 10f)) * direction) * Globals.dt.AsSeconds(), 0);
        }
        else
        {

            direction = _direction;
            heldfor /= 2;
            Velocity = new Vector2f(Velocity.X / 1.5f, Velocity.Y);
            if (heldfor < heldforlimit) heldfor++; 
            Velocity += new Vector2f(((speed * (heldfor / 10f)) * direction) * Globals.dt.AsSeconds(), 0);
        }

    }
    public void StopMoving()
    {
        moving = false;
        heldfor = 1;
    }

    public void Update(Time dt)
    {
        if(!moving)
        {
            if(Math.Abs(Velocity.X) - Globals.Friction.X < 0)
            {
                Velocity.X = 0;
            }
            else
            {   // i really should make this direction independent and apply direction at end of the update
                Velocity.X = Velocity.X > 0 ? Velocity.X - Globals.Friction.X : Velocity.X + Globals.Friction.X;
            }
            if (Math.Abs(Velocity.X) <= velocitySnapX) Velocity.X = 0;
            if (Math.Abs(Velocity.Y) <= velocitySnapY) Velocity.Y = 0;
        }
        if (Math.Abs(Velocity.X) > XMaxvel) Velocity.X = XMaxvel * direction;
        if (Math.Abs(Velocity.Y) > YMaxvel) Velocity.Y = YMaxvel * direction;
        Position += Velocity;
    }
}

class Program
{
    Player player = new Player();
    while(game.isrunning) // this is made up as the genuine code is too messy
    {
                    if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Right))
            {
                player.Move(1);
            }
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyPressed(Keyboard.Key.Left))
            {
                player.Move(-1);
            }
            window.Clear(Color.White);
            window.Draw(player);
            player.Update(Globals.dt);
            window.DispatchEvents();
            window.Display();
            window.SetView(mainview);
            Globals.dt = deltaclock.Restart();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to enforce a maximum cap on your time delta.

Building on Martin Sand's example:

```
// Get the time delta since last frame.
sf::Time dt = clock.restart();

// Convert to seconds, and clamp to your maximum time step.
float dtAsSeconds = std::min(dt.asSeconds(), 1f/30f);
```

That way, even if a frame runs really long, the game behaves as though a smaller amount of time passed, slowing down the action relative to wall clock time, rather than jumping ahead to try to catch up.

This can layer on top of a fixed timestep solution as well, leading you to perform fewer fixed ticks this frame to ensure you don't advance the simulation state too far in a single rendered frame.

Comment: sorry for answering a literal year later but thanks this probably should work

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend to start coding with the time step. The time step is the time between the different frames. There are several ways to handle this. The [Fix Your Timestep](https://gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/) web page summarizes them perfectly. It is kind of a reference.

Please find below same code sample. Code is for Linux but should also compile and work in Windows.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    // Timing
    sf::Clock clock;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Update the delta time to measure movement accurately
        sf::Time dt = clock.restart();

        // Convert to seconds to do the maths
        float dtAsSeconds = dt.asSeconds();

        // For debuging, print the time to the terminal
        // It illustrates the differences
        std::cout << "Time step: " << dtAsSeconds << '\n';

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```